# Prestashop | Generate multiple invoices from multiple orders

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a problem by generating multiple invoices in the Prestashop module.
What I did:

[image]

What I got:
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is most efficient working solution for the Prestashop 1.7.X**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tested,it works:

```
foreach ($orders as $o) {
  $order = new Order((int) $o['id_order']);
  foreach ($order->getInvoicesCollection() as $inv) {
    $invcs[] = $inv;
  }
}
$pdf = new PDF($invcs, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE, $this->context->smarty);
$pdf->render();
```

Problem was you were passing to PDF constructor an array containing PrestaShopCollection objects instead OrderInvoice objects.

Comment: You have a mistake here: PDF:TEMPLATE_INVOICE - should be PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE. Anyway your solution just prints 1 invoice - not the multiple. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. I have missunderstood the problem. You want to merge multiple order's invoices in an only PDF, but HTMLTemplateInvoice does not support that functionality.

Comment: who/what support's?

Comment: What is your PS version? I am surprised, because i saw 1.7.6.9 constructor and receive an OrderInvoice object, but in previous PS versions (at least 1.7.5.2) your code should work.

Comment: I have a version: 1.7.7.0